# Как правильно указать время для "обследую"?

Tags: словоприменение

Мне кажется, что у настоящего и будущего времени для слова "обследую(т)" одинаковая форма.

Так ли это?

Как правильно указать желаемое время?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всё верно. Есть ряд глаголов (в основном, на *-овать*), которые в зависимости от контекста передают совершенный или несовершенный вид, как то:

- *атаковать*
- *стартовать*
- *даровать*
- *образовать* (to constitute, to form)
- *организовать* (to organize)
- *афишировать, телеграфировать, механизировать* and some other verbs
- *жениться* (when a man marries a woman, not when they both "marry" each other)
- *казнить* (to execute a person)
- *ранить* (to wound)
- *исследовать* (to explore, to do research, to examine)
- *использовать* (to use)
- *заимствовать* (to borrow)

У таких глаголов личная форма передаёт либо настоящее, либо будущее время, в зависимости от контекста.

Short summary in English: yes, there is a small number of verbs in Russian that act for perfective or imperfective depending on the context (typically they end in *-овать*, but not all of them are like that).

Then, their conjugated form can mean present or future tense depending on your situation. If it is not clear in conversation or writing which time you might refer to, use additional adverbs of time or adverbial phrases to show that. Usually it is not necessary.

Comment: Such verbs are called "biaspectual" (*двувидовые*). http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_biaspectual_verbs

Answer (score 5):

You could use adverb to specify present tense explicitly:

> Пациента **сейчас** обследуют.

As it was stated correctly in comments, even this sentence can refer to *nearest future*. So you can specify present tense even more explicitly (this should leave no doubts):

> Пациента обследуют **в данный момент**.

Or use passive voice to specify future tense:

> Пациент **будет обследован.**

Comment: "Пациента сейчас обследуют" - тоже двусмысленно. То ли его обследуют в настоящий момент, то ли его будут обследовать в ближайший момент.